# Managing Shared Memory in C on OSX

Tags: c, macos, unix, shared-memory

I am working on a university assignment, based largely around IPC and shared memory.  The problem is, as a complete noob to C, I've been happily testing my app (which uses `shmget` and  `shmat` obviously) for hours.  As you can probably guess, I've not been cleaning up after myself, and now I can't run my app, because (I assume) `shmget` cant allocate anymore resources.

My question is: how can I get this resource back without restarting OSX, and is there a GUI tool or something I can use to monitor/manage this shared memory I am creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`shmdt`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shmdt.html) ("shared memory detach") on the shared memory segment in each process that holds a reference to it. Unix shared memory sections are reference counted, so when the last process detaches from them, they can be destroyed with [`shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, NULL)`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shmctl.html).

From outside your application, the only option I can think of right now to clear your shared memory segments is:

```
for (int id=0; id < INT_MAX; id++)
    shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
```

but this is a horribly inefficient kludge. (I'm also not sure if it works; it doesn't on Linux, but Linux violates the Unix standard while MacOS X is certified against it.)

Comment: That's actually really useful, but if I haven't done that yet, can I release all the shared memory via Terminal or something?

Comment: I posted an update with a code snippet that should do that. I'm not on a MacOS X box, so I can't check for commands that do this for you. Try `man shmget` etc. and look at the `SEE ALSO` sections.

Comment: ok rad, thanks.  As for your suggestion, am I correct in my usage when I call `shmdt(shm_id);` where shm_id is the int that I get when I originally called `shmget()` ?  What if I have forked the process, does the shmget reference also get cloned (so that if one forked process calls `shmdt()` the OS wont destroy the memory from the other?)

Comment: Your first assumption is correct. I can't find the behavior across forks in the Unix standard; Solaris apparently passes the segment to child processes. I'd advise you to switch to `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED` (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) if at all possible; that interface is *much* simpler to use.

Comment: Since this id for a university assignment, I dont think I am allowed to.  But I'll keep an eye on behaviour and see what happens.

Comment: Running `printf("shmdt returns: %d\n", shmdt(shm_id));` always seems to return -1 which the page you linked to in your answer says "Otherwise, the shared memory segment shall not be detached, shmdt() shall return -1".  Where `shm_id = shmget(SHM_KEY, N * sizeof (FILE_entry), IPC_CREAT | 0644);` - have I done something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `shmget` for -1?

Comment: The return value is always -1 (see above).  Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: For `shmget`, not for `shmdt`. Do you actually get valid ids?

Comment: no, but i execute `entries = (FILE_entry *) shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);` which I can store data into just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry Ash, I'm afraid can't help you further. Please read your manpages carefully for MacOS X behavior, post a new question, or impress your professor with an `mmap`-based solution.

Comment: The `IPC_STAT` isn't necessary - `shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, NULL);` is fine (it's the `id`, not the `shmid_ds`, that determines the shared memory segment to operate on).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit late, but there are cmdline tools available to do exactly this. 
ipcs and ipcrm

take a look at their man pages.