# Management of Unix Shared Memory

Tags: unix, shared-memory

We know that, shared memory in Windows is implemented via memory mapped files backed by system pagefile, and it is always managed in a reference counted way (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx).

I wonder whether Unix does it in a similar way. Someone (http://stackoverflow.com/q/4278391/939142) says that Unix also manages shm in a reference counted way. I tried the an experiment on Mac OS X, and found that it was not the case.

Using the code supplied in the end, compile two programs: host and client. Type

```
./host
```

which creates a shm, writes (int) 10 at its first address, and quits. Then type

```
./client <shmid>
```

to examine the shm segment, which attaches to the shm created, prints the first int, and quits.

Note that we used shmat and shmdt to connect to / disconnect from the shm, and shmget to create the shm.

To destroy the shm, we have to do it manually using shmctl.

Conclusion:
shm is not managed as reference counting in Unix, at least for Mac OS X

```
/************************** host.c ****************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <mach/vm_param.h>
#include <assert.h>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int value = 10;
int id;
void* ptr;
    /* create a new shm */
id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, PAGE_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
assert(id != -1);
    /* attach to the new shm */
ptr = shmat(id, (const void*) NULL, 0);
assert((int*) ptr != -1);
    /* print the id so that client can use */
printf("shm id = %ld\n", id);
printf("address of id = %ld, length = %ld\n", ptr, PAGE_SIZE);
((int*) ptr)[0] = value;
printf("value at address %ld = %ld\n", ptr, *(int*) ptr);
/* detach from the shm and exit */
    shmdt((const void*) ptr);
return 0;
}


/************************** host.c ****************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include "assert.h"
#include <mach/vm_param.h>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
void* ptr;
int id = atoi(argv[1]);
assert(id != -1);
    /* attach to the shm */
ptr = shmat(id, NULL, 0);
assert(ptr != -1);
printf("value at ptr = %ld = %ld\n", ptr, *(int*) ptr);
shmdt((const void*) ptr);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It not *pure* reference counting. According to shmctl(2):

> **IPC_RMID**:  Mark the segment to be  destroyed.   The  segment  will  only
>                    actually  be  destroyed  after  the  last process detaches it
>                    (i.e., when the shm_nattch member of the associated structure
>                    shmid_ds  is zero).  The caller must be the owner or creator,

This means: `IPC_RMID` will not delete immediately but only after the reference count drops to zero the next time.

This allows you to achieve several goals with the same tool:

- Either a server/client approach where the server creates, attaches and immediately sets `RMID`. Then clients can connect as long as the server is here. If the server goes down, the clients should disconect and the resource is cleaned up by the OS.
- Or the "message" approach: Someone writes a message, pins it to a known location. After that someone else can come, look for a message and act accordingly. This is what you have done. This approach is more open to resource garbage of course. But there are usecases for this.

Comment: Sweet explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: I just found that your manage comes from Linux, and the "mark" behavior is not portable to other *nix systems. I tried another experiment on both Mac OS X and Debian. In Mac OS X, the shm is deleted immediately upon a valid IPC_RMID command.

Comment: @stoictopia: According to the booke "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment" by Richard Stevens the `IPC_RMID` behaviour of Linux is standard-conform with one exception: Linux allow to re-attach _after_ `IPC_RMID`. Other OSes don't. But in _all_ cases the shm segment is still alive for everyone who has been already attached. This means you cannot simply pull the rug from under a process with `IPC_RMID`. I think you mixed those two different things into one.

Comment: I see. I can view the opened shm via ipcs. On both systems the shm is still attached after IPC_RMID and before the last shmdt. However, there is still at least one difference: on Debian, refcount = 1 is still valid after IPC_RMID until the last shmdt, whereas on OSX, refcount is no longer valid after IPC_RMID.

Comment: As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42479369/2732969 it's not just Linux that has "attach after `IPC_RMID`" semantics . Some other OSes (FreeBSD at version 11) have even switched from what they had to Linux-style behaviour but sadly macOS (at least up to 10.15) is not in this category.